# ПУСТЬ - это общий член?

Tags: запятые

> Пусть у ребенка будет стремление хоть к чему-нибудь(,) и пусть он будет хотя бы чем-то занят!

Я правильно понимаю, что *пусть* - это общий член предложений и запятая в скобках не нужна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, частица *пусть* не является общим членом предложений в составе сложносочиненного: она просто повторяется в обеих половинах.

Чтобы она была общей, необходимо убрать её повтор:

*Пусть у ребенка будет стремление хоть к чему-нибудь и он будет хотя бы чем-то занят!*

Однако, в данном примере, обе части сложносочиненного предложения выражены побудительными предложениями. Поэтому, согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §112. (...) В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами *и*, *да* (в значении «и»), *или*, *либо* запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:
>
> (...)
>
> 5) если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация.

Так что запятая тут не ставится, но не из-за общей частицы *пусть*:

*Пусть у ребенка будет стремление хоть к чему-нибудь и пусть он будет хотя бы чем-то занят!*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: А не может здесь быть общая восклицательная интонация (ведь предложение с восклицательным знаком), и тогда без запятой?